# C Built in Functions

Tags: c, function

I have code that gives me an error. Implicit declaration of isNumericFloat.
I want to know if the function:

```
isNumericFloat()
```

a built it function in C?

Comment: It's not, where is your code?

Comment: C doesn't really have *built in functions* - there are standard libraries that provide commonly used functionality

Comment: ... and even the functions in the standard library should be declared before they are used by including the appropriate header file.  If that is not done then the compiler will make the same complaint about *them*, too.

Comment: found the definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, it's not a "*built-in*" c function.<sup>1</sup>

This function is used somewhere in your code and it's not part of the standard library. In fact, just because it uses camel case which is not very common in c code it seems like an odd function written by a not so c-ish programmer, of course that's a subjective reason, but commonly c programmers would choose `is_numeric_float()`.

You need to search your code to see if you can find it's defintion, but in the mean time you can provide a prototype, like

```
int isNumericFloat(float value); // I don't really know what arguments it takes
                                 // but you can surely infer them from the code
```

before it's ever called in the code, if you do so one of these two things will happen

1. If there is a definition for the function somewhere, it will compile fine.
2. If there is no definition, the linker will tell you that there is/are undefined reference/s to it in the code.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Strictly speaking, there are no built-in functions in c, there is something called the standard library (*headers starting with **std** , like **stdlib.h***), and I mean that it's not part of such library.</sub>